# Why constinit of half-initialized struct does not work

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

```
struct A1 { int x;     int y; };
struct A2 { int x = 1; int y = 2; };
struct A3 { int x = 1; int y; };

constinit A1 a1; // x == 0, y == 0.
constinit A2 a2; // x == 1, y == 2.
          A3 a3; // x == 1, y == 0.
constinit A3 a4; // Error: illegal initialization of 'constinit' entity with a non-constant expression

int main() {}
```

What is the problem with `a4`? I mean `a4.x` should be initialized by a constant `1` (same as for `a2` where it works) and `a4.y` by a constant `0` because `a4` is a global static variable (same as for `a1` where it works).

Now, considering that both MSVC and GCC fail to compile this code I assume the standard somehow forbids it. But any way I look at `a4` its initial value is exact, constant and known at compile time so why the standard forbids us from declaring it as `constinit`)?

In addition to this, `clang++` also rejects the first `constinit`ialization:

```
error: variable does not have a constant initializer
constinit A1 a1;  // x == 0, y == 0.
```

Comment: clang [also rejects](https://godbolt.org/z/xW95zG178) `constinit A1 a1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a case where we might be missing some wording.

To start with, there are three stages of initialization that happen ([[basic.start.static]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.start.static)):

1. Constant initialization
2. If not that, zero-initialization (for static storage duration variables, like the ones in this question)
3. If necessary, dynamic initialization

(1) and (2) together are static initialization, (3) is... well, dynamic. And what `constinit` does is ensure that there is no dynamic iniitialization, from [[dcl.constinit]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.constinit):

> If a variable declared with the `constinit` specifier has dynamic initialization ([basic.start.dynamic]), the program is ill-formed.

And the rule for constant initialization is, from [[expr.const]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const):

> A variable or temporary object `o` is *constant-initialized* if
>
> - either it has an initializer or its default-initialization results in some initialization being performed, and
> - the full-expression of its initialization is a constant expression when interpreted as a *constant-expression*, except that if `o` is an object, that full-expression may also invoke constexpr constructors for `o` and its subobjects even if those objects are of non-literal class types.

---

With that said, let's go through the three types. Starting with the easiest:

```cpp
struct A2 { int x = 1; int y = 2; };
constinit A2 a2; // x == 1, y == 2.
```

Here, we're initializing all the members, this is clearly constant initialization. Not really much of a question here.

Next:

```cpp
struct A1 { int x;     int y; };
constinit A1 a1; // x == 0, y == 0.
```

Here, our default constructor does... nothing, there is no initialization. So this is not constant initialization. But zero-initialization happens and then there is no further initialization. There is certainly no dynamic initialization that has to take place here, so there is nothing for `constinit` to diagnose.

Lastly:

```cpp
struct A3 { int x = 1; int y; };
constinit A3 a4; // Error: illegal initialization of 'constinit' entity with a non-constant expression
```

Prior to the adoption of [P1331](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1331r2.pdf), this initialization of `a4` was clearly not constant initialization because constant initialization explicitly required fully initialized variables. But we don't have this requirement anymore, the rule was moved later - to when `a4.y` would actually be read.

But I think the intent in this case is very much that `a4` is *not* constant initialized, due to it being partially uninitialized. This probably merits a core issue.

Given that it is not constant initialization, then we go into zero initialization. But after that, `a4` still isn't fully initialized - because we have to set `x` to `1`. There is no provision for half-constant half-zero initialization. The rule is constant or, if not that, zero. Since this isn't (or, at least, shouldn't be) constant initialization, and zero-initialization is insufficient, `a4` must undergo dynamic initialization. And thus, `constinit` should flag this case. gcc and msvc are correct here (clang erroneously rejects `a1`).

Comment: The way [\[dcl.init\]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init#7.sentence-1) is worded makes it seem that only non-class types can be default-initialized without "_initialization being performed_". The wording of [\[basic.life\]/1 sentence 2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic#life-1.sentence-2) with [\[basic.life\]/1.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic#life-1.2) also seems to indicate that. With that interpretation it seems to me that `a1` and `a4` should behave the same, although I am unsure this is the intended interpretation. Am I wrong?

Comment: @user17732522 Default initializing a class type with a trivial default constructor is just as much no-initialization as default initializing an int. The 2nd link talks about when a default-initialized object of class type has vacuous initialization - so I am not sure why you think that indicates that objects of class type can't have no initialization.

Comment: "But I think the intent in this case is very much that `a4` is not constant initialized" - but which quotes from C++20 formally explain that initialization of `a4` would or would not be constant initialization?

Comment: @PowerGamer Did you read the part where I said that we're missing wording that covers this case and the history behind the current wording? The previous wording that prevented it from being constant initialization no longer exists, yet it is definitely not constant initialized -- since the relaxation that eliminated that rule wasn't about this case.

Comment: @Barry For a non-class type 7.3. says explicitly that "no initialization is performed". For a class type with trivial default constructor 7.1. seems to still say that the default constructor is called to initialize the object. I am wondering why the trivial default constructor call wouldn't count as dynamic initialization if leaving the members uninitialized isn't allowed for constant-initialization. I guess a user-provided empty default constructor would count as such. I don't see where in the standard the distinction is made (but I may just be missing it).

Comment: @user17732522 There's no reason for it to count as dynamic initialization - nothing happens. There is reason for it to _not_ count as constant initialization - the object is not completely initialized. That's not very constant, if it's indeterminate.

Comment: But a function call, even if it doesn't do anything, can still cause an object to have dynamic initialization, can't it? E.g. `constinit struct A { int x; constexpr A() {} } a;` should be ill-formed because `a` has dynamic initialization, but `constinit struct A { int x; A() = default; } a;` shouldn't be? So trivial default constructors are exempt somewhere?